# How do I use an actionButton to delay a defined function?

Tags: r, shiny

I can see how to use actionButton to delay an output, but I haven't seen an example relevant to what I am trying to do, which is delay the start of a defined function that is called within another output.

Simplified for the MRE, let's say I have an output to create the mean of a data set. I have three ways to calculate the mean. One of those ways takes a long time though (simulated here by Method 2). Here is the way it is structured now.

How can I get algo(x) to wait until the button is pressed, then start the calculation and return the value?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
            radioButtons(inputId = "calc_t",label = "Select Calculation",choices = c("Method 1"=1,"Method 2 (long)"=2,"Method 3"=3)),
            actionButton(inputId = "go_algo",label = "Start Algo")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           textOutput("analyze")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
    
    output$analyze <- renderText({
      calc_type<-input$calc_t
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      if(calc_type==1){
        output<-paste("Mean 1 = ",mean(x))
      } else if (calc_type==2){
        output<-paste("Mean 2 = ",algo(x))
      } else if(calc_type==3){
        output<-paste("Mean 3 = ",sum(x)/length(x))
      }
    })
    
    algo<-function(x){
      mean_x<-mean(x)
      #stuff that would take a long time
      output<-mean_x+100
      return(output)
    }
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you want Method 1 and Method 3 to calculate immediately when switching the ```radioButtons```, but only Method 2 to require the ```actionButton``` press?

Comment: @Silentdevildoll Yes, exactly.

Comment: It's possible just adding ```req(input$go_algo)``` in ```else if (calc_type==2){req(input$go_algo) output<-paste("Mean 2 = ",algo(x))}``` is all you need.

Comment: @Silentdevildoll That is perfect and very simple. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Silentdevildoll  Oops, it looks like once you click it, it will process every time after that without waiting on the button. It is hard to tell in the MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an `observeEvent` for the action button for the function that needs to wait for the button. For this observeEvent a `req` is required to limit the button to work only for this choice. Then you can use another `observeEvent` for the the other choices and again limit what is allowed to run without a button click with `req`.
Here's the updated server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
         main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$calc_t, {
    req(input$calc_t!=2)
    output$analyze <- renderText({
      
      calc_type<-input$calc_t
      x <- faithful[, 2]
      if(calc_type==1){
        output<-paste("Mean 1 = ",mean(x))
      } else if(calc_type==3){
        output<-paste("Mean 3 = ",sum(x)/length(x))
      }
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go_algo, {
    req(input$calc_t==2)
    output$analyze <- renderText({
      
      isolate(calc_type<-input$calc_t)
      x <- faithful[, 2]
      output<-paste("Mean 2 = ",algo(x))
    })
  })
  
  
  algo<-function(x){
    mean_x<-mean(x)
    #stuff that would take a long time
    output<-mean_x+100
    return(output)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this doesn't quite help. I only want the algo function to wait on the button, the others can be calculated in the moment.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that. Hope that this is what you're looking for!

Comment: This would absolutely work in the MRE I gave you. The problem is that in the real script, the calculations can't be separated out into observeEvent()s so easily due to my inexpert scripting. I ended up storing and checking against a global variable to trigger the long calculation.